# How to send an octet-stream with Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios, linkedin-api

I am following the LinkedIn documentations [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api?tabs=http#upload-the-video) to upload a file as an octet stream to the LinkedIn Assets API, but I keep getting back an empty response

This is the curl example they gave

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --upload-file /Users/username/SampleVideo_2mb.mp4 'https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5400AQHpR1ANqMWqNA/uploadedVideo/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads_secure&ccn=ambry-video&m=AQLEZ2pjh43pagYYYXRaCyztOykwDzluHkkYTbsMjNUzivrEOeObw9h3&app=1234&sync=1&v=beta&ut=1KeEm4JnMnJpo1'
```

What is the proper axios equivalent of the above code?

Here is what I tried in NodeJS

```
    let uploadHeaders = uploadRegisterData['uploadMechanism']['com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest']['headers'];

    let videoUploadFinaleResponse = await axios.put(uploadUrl, fs.createReadStream(fileName), {
           headers: {
           'Accept': '*/*',
            ...uploadHeaders,
           'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
          }
      });
    let uploadedVideoData = videoUploadFinaleResponse.data; //This is always coming back as an empty string
```

The response data is always coming back as an empty string `""`.

I have a feeling my axios code equivalent is somehow wrong.

How can I get this right?

Thank you.

Comment: did you figure this out eventually?

Comment: the example code looks good and should work